# What are the restrictions to ssh StrictHostKeyChecking=no?

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

When running ssh with StrictHostKeyChecking=no, it should always accept CHANGED keys.
However it does not in my case. This is documented in the man page (ssh-config):

```
 StrictHostKeyChecking
         If this flag is set to yes, ssh(1) will never automatically
         add host keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses
         to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.  This
         provides maximum protection against man-in-the-middle
         (MITM) attacks, though it can be annoying when the
         /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file is poorly maintained or when
         connections to new hosts are frequently made.  This option
         forces the user to manually add all new hosts.

         If this flag is set to “accept-new” then ssh will
         automatically add new host keys to the user's known_hosts
         file, but will not permit connections to hosts with changed
         host keys.  If this flag is set to “no” or “off”, ssh will
         automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts
         files and allow connections to hosts with changed hostkeys
         to proceed, subject to some restrictions.  If this flag is
         set to ask (the default), new host keys will be added to
         the user known host files only after the user has confirmed
         that is what they really want to do, and ssh will refuse to
         connect to hosts whose host key has changed.  The host keys
         of known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases.
```

This section is relevant:
*If this flag is set to “**no**” or “off”, ssh will
automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts
files and **allow connections to hosts with changed hostkeys**
to proceed, **subject to some restrictions**.*

What are the mentioned restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak from experience. You won't be able to open a remote tunnel with the connection. This happens regardless of setting the `ExitOnForwardFailure=no` option, which when set to `yes` will terminate the connection immediately in this situation. So it appears that the SSH client still handles an offending `known_host` entry as an error.

If there are more restrictions, I can not tell.